# Selenium | While Running the scripts through Maven in Command Prompt I am getting ExecutionException There was an error in the forked process

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

```
Please refer to ..\atsp_automation_v1.0\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
 Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
 ExecutionException There was an error in the forked process

 Cannot find class in classpath: <classname>
 org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: ExecutionException There was an error in the forked process

 Cannot find class in classpath: <clasname>
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.awaitResultsDone(ForkStarter.java:496)
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.runSuitesForkPerTestSet(ForkStarter.java:443)
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:295)
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:246)
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1124)
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:954)
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:832)
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:955)*
```